# Can users download files from AWS SSE-KMS encrypted S3 bucket via AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

A little bit of context, we would like to use AWS SSE-KMS on our S3 bucket to encrypt our plaintext object uploads. I'm planning to only allow these permissions to an IAM role only used by our ec2 instances

- kms:GenerateDataKey
- kms:Decrypt

What would normal users using our AWS account see when downloading objects from our bucket? Would the objects be encrypted since they don't have KMS permissions? Are they able to download these objects at all?

Thanks

Comment: If the KMS key policy permits kms:Decrypt and kms:GenerateDataKey to the relevant signed-in IAM user and that user has the requisite S3 and KMS permissions then this should be seamless. Other users should see 403 Forbidden (or some form of Access Denied message). Should be easy to test and confirm this.

Comment: Actually, for downloading purposes, the console IAM users should only need kms:Decrypt on the KMS key, not kms:GenerateDataKey, and s3:GetObject on the relevant object(s) though they probably should also have s3:ListAllMyBuckets, s3:GetBucketLocation, and s3:ListBucket for console navigation purposes.